# Replace substring of text matching regexp

Tags: java, regex

I have text that looks like something like this:

```
1. Must have experience in Java 2. Team leader...
```

I want to render this in HTML as an ordered list. Now adding the `</li>` tag to the end is simple enough:

```
s = replace(s, ". ", "</li>");
```

But how do I go about replacing the `1.`, `2.` etc with `<li>`?

I have the regular expression `\d*\.$` which matches a number with a period, but the problem is is that is a substring so matching `1. Must have experience in Java 2. Team leader` with `\d*\.$` returns `false`.

Comment: @Reimeus the user isn't parsing HTML, they're trying to generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Zrz6GF/1)

```
\d+\.\s+(.*?)\s*(?=\d+\.\s+|$)
```

Replace

```
<li>$1</li>\n
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> 1. Must have experience in Java 2. Team leader...

#### Output

```
<li>Must have experience in Java</li>
<li>Team leader...</li>
```

---

### Explanation

- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
- `(.*?)` Capture any character any number of times, but as few as possible, into capture group 1
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `(?=\d+\.\s+|$)` Positive lookahead ensuring either of the following doesn't match

  1. `\d+\.\s+`

     - `\d+` Match one or more digits
     - `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
     - `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
  2. `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

> But how do I go about replacing the `1.`, `2.` etc with `<li>`?

You can use [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which can allow regex instead of replace :

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\d+\\.\\s", "</li>");
```

**Note**

- You don't need to use `$` in the end of your regex.
- You have to escape dot `.` because it's mean any character in regex
- You can use `\s` for one space or `\s*` for zero or more spaces or \s+ for one or more space

Comment: This works, (although in your answer your string replaces the regex match with `</li>` when it needs to be `<li>`) but @ctwheels answer is much more robust.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood that comment. If you look at @ctwheels's answer under "output" it's exactly what I'm looking for. Though to be fair I was more interested in getting the opening `<li>` tag, the closing one was less complicated.

Comment: its ok @mohammedkhan it was just a comment and i'm happy that ctwheels answer help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

We want

```
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two<li>
</ol>
```

This can be done as:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?s)(\\d+\\.)\\s+(.*\\.)\\s*", "<li>$2</li></ol>");
s = s.replaceFirst("<li>", "<ol><li>");
s = s.replaceAll("(?s)</li></ol><li>", "</li>\n<li>");
```

The trick is to first add `</li></ol>` with a spurious `</ol>` that should only remain after the last list item.

`(?s)` is the DOTALL notation, causing `.` to also match line breaks.

In case of more than one numbered list this will not do. Also it assumes one single sentence per list item.